# Add-BindingRedirect : Loading this assembly would produce a different grant set from other instances

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-4.8, nuget-package-restore

I have inherited an old project (.NET web site with a `.publishproj` file!) that has project dependencies on other .NET class libraries.  Everything is .NET 4.8.  I am trying to run `Add-BindingRedirect` from the Package Manager Console, which was working up until recently, and am now getting the following error:

> Add-BindingRedirect : Loading this assembly would produce a different
> grant set from other instances. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131401)
> At line:1 char:20
>
> - Get-Project -all | Add-BindingRedirect
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-BindingRedirect], FileLoadException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.AddBindingRedirectCommand

The .NET web site project has a web.config file with binding redirects that are causing me heartache, and the .NET libraries have app.config files.  I need all these projects to share the same binaries.

I can't even run this command on ONE project without getting this error, let alone all the projects at once.

I have tried recycling all my application pools in IIS, restarting with IIS Express, deleting all the `.suo` files in the various projects, restarting VS, restarting my machine.  I haven't seen anything relating to this error in this context.

Comment: What is your Visual Studio version? I had the same issue in Visual Studio 17.5.5. Downgrading to 17.5.4 helped.

Comment: Same problem here with version Version 17.5.5. In visual studio 2019 16.11.26 works ok

Comment: I'm on v17.6.3 and getting this error...

Comment: Update: Tested with a colleague who is also on v17.6.3 and it works as expected. This doesn't seem to be tied to the VS version necessarily...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was facing the same issue when attempting to run this command, but managed to run it by creating the DWORD variable `LoaderOptimization` with `1` for value under the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework`, then restarting Visual Studio and running the command in the Package Manager Console again.

Found the details in this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-dotnet/issues/475)

Comment: After doing this, I had to restart Visual Studio

Comment: You have saved my life.